In how many ways can we seat 6 people around a table if two person insist on sitting opposite each other
In how many ways can we seat 6 people around a table if two person insist on sitting opposite each other?
It is a permutation and combination question.
I tried solving it like - two persons have 3 ways to sit opposite to each other amd they can arrange themselves in 2 ways and remaining 4 can be arranged in 3! Ways. So 3×2×3! But my answer is not correct

Welcome on MSE. If all your guest move to the seat to their right, do you count this as a new configuration, or do you count it as the same? More precisely, are you considering the seats as numbered, so that the total number of sittings is $6!$?

If all the guests move towards their right, then that will be counted as the same arrangement only.

The answer given below takes that convention: the number of way the guests can be seated relatively to the two persons who insist on sitting opposite to each other is just the number of way to sit the four remaining persons in four seats!

Unless otherwise explicitly mentioned, a round table seating is taken to have unnumbered seats, so any arrangement remains unchanged on rotation
So suppose we seat the special two A,B at imaginary north south points, all we need to do is too permute the remaining $4$ in $4!$ ways

Ok now I got it. I was earlier taking the seats to be numbered. Thank you!!

You're welcome !
